# Insert into without defining PK results in violation of PK Constraint

Tags: sql-server, vb6

Iam running a sql statement that will fail in around 1 of every 100.000 requests (so very rarely).
My problem is that the error message makes no sense.

I have a table with a PK called ID, i make an

```
INSERT INTO log_db (col1,col2) OUTPUT inserted.ID SELECT col3,col4 FROM otherTable
```

The ID column is not specified so the SQLServer should generate this automatically and ensure no dublicates are created.

SQLServer Error message:

> -2147217900 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_log_db'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.log_db'. The duplicate key value is (556943).

Requests are being made using ADO in VB6 against a SQLserver 2012.

Comment: May be some other insert is happening 1 of every 100.000 requests

Comment: Nope i can see the line that is failing is the one above where i dont specify the PK in the insert (it is an auto incremented identity). And as far as i know there should be no way for the SQL server to try to insert the same PK when the table has an auto incremented identity.

Answer (score 0):

When this error occurs, use DBCC CHECKIDENT ('log_db', NORESEED) to see if a value higher than the current identity value has been inserted.

The results of this vary, so you should ignore the standard message and just look at the numbers. If the first number is less than the second, a record has been inserted in this way and your identity value is out of sync with the data values.